# Django form not visible

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Only the button is visible and headings are visible cannot see CharField

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

class NameForm(forms.Form):
    your_name = forms.CharField(label='Your name', max_length=100)
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from compare.forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = NameForm(request.POST)
   if form.is_valid():
      return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

   else:
      form = NameForm()

   return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

**index.htm**

```
    <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: I think you have been down voted because you haven't given enough context to your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should give the if form.is_valid() part, one more tab.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from compare.forms import NameForm

def get_name(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
      form = NameForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid():
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

   else:
      form = NameForm()

   return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Actually, i am a beginner can u plz explain where to add form.is_valid(), though I hav used it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not yet allowed to add comments to your question, but you did notice, that your view renders *name.html* while you're providing the code for *index.htm*.

Basically your code seems valid, while it can be further optimized:

```
def get_name(request):
    form = NameForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')

    return render(request, 'name.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: My bad. Ya that was a mistake, I corrected it still no luck. Btw thank a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

```
 <form action="/your-name/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

This should work by adding editing `{{form.as_p}}`

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned-upon. You should add an explanation of how this fixes the original problem (especially as your change doesn't appear to match the accepted answer).